# How do I getcpuid() on Linux?

Tags: c, linux

How do I programmatically get the core a given thread is running on? Something like Unix's `getcpuid`. This is for Linux, and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [sched_getcpu()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html) not give you a different value for the cores?